# How to check for completion of two simultaneous requests with Restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular, angular-promise

I am doing 2 requests using Restangular,

```
  Restangular.all('clients').getList().then(function(clients) {
    $scope.clients = clients;
  });
  Restangular.all('suppliers').getList().then(function(suppliers) {
    $scope.suppliers = suppliers;
  });
```

I want to run some code after it they finish, how can i do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) and add both the promises as input. And you would need to inject `$q`.

```
  var clientsPromise = Restangular.all('clients').getList().then(function(clients) {
     $scope.clients = clients;
  });
  var suppliersPromise = Restangular.all('suppliers').getList().then(function(suppliers) {
     $scope.suppliers = suppliers;
  });

   $q.all([clientsPromise, suppliersPromise])
     .then(function(results){ //This will execute only when both the promises have been fulfilled
       //Do something;
   });
```

For more readability you could as well do:-

```
 function populateClients(){
    return Restangular.all('clients').getList().then(function(clients) {
       $scope.clients = clients;
    });
 }

 function populateSuppliers(){
    return Restangular.all('suppliers').getList().then(function(suppliers) {
      $scope.suppliers = suppliers;
   });
 }

 $q.all([populateClients(), populateSuppliers()]).then(doSomethingFn, handleError);
```

Success callback of q.all will run only when both the promises are resolved, if one of them fails it will go to `catch` block and you can use `finally` which will run when all are fulfilled.